# How do I find a common solution of this recurrence equation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find a common solution of this recurrence equation:
$y_{n+2} - 2 y_{n+1} - 8 y_n = \sin (n+1)$

Consider the homogeneous equation $y_{n+2} - 2 y_{n+1} - 8 y_n = 0$. It has a common solution $y_n = c_1 (-2)^n + c_2 4^n$.

In what form should I look for a particular solution?

Answer (score 3):

It will be $y_p = A\cos n + B\sin n$

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I should equate the coefficients of the $\sin n$ and $\cos n$ and to obtain a linear system of second order on $A$ and $B$?